# How to simplify Restler Luracast repository for various environments and development?

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

So basically I have the code from the repository, which comes with a lot of things like the public folder which is not necessary for it to work.

I want to know what is the simplified version of the repository so that if I have a test environment and a production environment I can commit code and just deploy it on the right place.
As an example, the index.php is a file that needs to change to turn off debug to optimize it for production... The first solution I see would be to set it up in different branches and add a .gitignore file to ignore the index.php. But I am not sure if this is the optimal solution. Maybe there is a simplified structure within the whole Restler structure that I can just put in version control instead of the whole original repository.

Any tips?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-Framework holds just the restler codebase needed for your app excluding its own examples and tests.

https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-Application contains application templates to quickly get started with various integrations in each of its branches. It uses the `restler/framework` from the above repository.

Just select the branch that suits your needs and follow the instructions in the readme